# What is the difference between a browser request and a curl request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, curl, firefox

https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2016-47119-002

When I access the above URL by chrome (in a private window), I can see the first request which corresponds to the following `curl` command. But when I call this `curl` command in the command line, it will be detected by distil network showing `<div id="distilIdentificationBlock">&nbsp;</div>`
.

This looks strange to me as this is the first request. Unless there is a difference between the requests send by curl and chrome, there is no way by which distil network can tell what request is sent by a bot or by a real browser. Does anybody know what is the difference between the curl request and the chrome request?

```
curl 'https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2016-47119-002' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7' \
  --compressed
```

P.S. The problem is same if I use firefox to extract the corresponding curl command. So the difference between firefox request and curl request is also relevant.

Comment: This question should be renamed to "How does Distill detect and block curl requests compared to Chrome requests?"

Comment: Please make the change as you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference.

To find out how Distill (their web-scraping protection system) works, you need to look at the initial response HTML:

When I make the request in Chrome and look at the initial response in the Dev Tools (make sure "Preserve log" is checked) I see that the response is actually a short web-page that contains an embedded `<script>` which performs some simple "is this user-agent a web-browser?" checks, like running scripts that look for JavaScript DOM objects that won't exist outside of a web-browser (assuming the HTTP user-agent is capable of running scripts at all - which `cURL` and `wget` aren't, by the way).

If the script considers your user-agent to be a web-browser then it performs another request for the real content using a dynamically generated password (I didn't look at the details for how *that* works) - which is why you can't re-request the real content using `cURL` or `wget` as the password is unique for each request.

Here's a screenshot of the `<script>` element in the initial page response, and notice the lack of real actual content in the page's HTML.

[image]

If you disable JavaScript in your browser you won't be able to access that web-page at all.

This kind of anti-scraping system protects web-pages against requests from user-agents that lack the means to evaluate JavaScript - so it will block `curl`, `wget`, `HttpClient`, and in-browser `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequests` (at least not without further work).

You'd think this system would render a site un-indexable by search-engine spiders - but that's an old (and entrenched) belief and practice: because until the late-2000s the main search engine spiders (Google, Bing/Windows Live Search, Yahoo, etc) only indexed raw HTML and didn't run JavaScript - but since then the search-engine spiders started running JavaScript and even started indexing sites not using custom-built spider HTML-parser engines but using actual web-browser engines (Google really started it, so that they could index script-heavy websites, especially single-page-applications using Angular, Vue, etc). When I worked at Microsoft I got to use the Bing crawler system for some product research projects and that used a special build of Internet Explorer to "run" web-pages that it visited.

Comment: This is an informed reply. Is there a way to mimic the javascript ability of a browser but without starting a full-fledged browser (e.g., not via selenium)?